# Bluetooth adapter not found Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: bluetooth

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 on an HP Spectre x360 15T laptop.  It has Intel Wifi 6 AX201 wireless which is both Wifi and Bluetooth.  In Ubuntu, the Wifi is working fine but no Bluetooth adapter is found.

In Windows 10, both Wifi and Bluetooth appear to be working fine.

My output from rfkill is:

misen@misen-spectre$ rfkill list all

0: phy0: Wireless LAN

```
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Any help would be appreciated.

dmesg output below

$ dmesg |grep -i firm

[    0.553031] tpm tpm0: [Firmware Bug]: TPM interrupt not working, polling instead
[    2.173675] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm

[    2.241919] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)

[    2.295084] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.

Comment: it seems like this is a distribution issue itself that needs to be fixed.
I found an error on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-oem/+bug/1853665), it is very similar to your problem. Vote for the bug to fix it faster.

Comment: Did you scan the dmesg output for firmware loading errors?  Try dmesg |grep -i firm  and report the results here by editing your question.